# How to form search url for nexus 3

Tags: rest, maven, lucene, nexus, nexus3

We have migrated our Nexus repo from Version 2.x to 3.0. I have confusion on how to modify the nexus url now. Please help on this

```
Nexus 2.x url:
http://{NEXUS_URL}/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=com.test.furycom

Please help what i need to modify in above url to make it work for Nexus 3
```

Comment: You can find documentation for the new Nexus Repo 3 REST API here:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/REST+and+Integration+API